# How to divide the sum with the size in a pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
  ID_0 ID_1  ID_2
0    a    b     1
1    a    c     1
2    a    b     0
3    d    c     0
4    a    c     0
5    a    c     1
```

I would like to groupby ['ID_0','ID_1'] and produce a new dataframe which has the sum of the ID_2 values for each group divided by the number of rows in each group.

```
grouped  = df.groupby(['ID_0', 'ID_1'])
print grouped.agg({'ID_2': np.sum}), "\n", grouped.size()
```

gives

```
           ID_2
ID_0 ID_1
a    b        1
     c        2
d    c        0
ID_0  ID_1
a     b       2
      c       3
d     c       1
dtype: int64
```

How can I  get the new dataframe with the np.sum values divided by the size() values?

Comment: Isn't what you're looking for just the mean?  i.e. `df.groupby(['ID_0', 'ID_1']).mean()`

Comment: @root In this case you are right! But I really wanted to know the general method.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `groupby.apply` instead:

```
df.groupby(['ID_0', 'ID_1']).apply(lambda x: x['ID_2'].sum()/len(x))

ID_0  ID_1
a     b       0.500000
      c       0.666667
d     c       0.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I make a proper dataframe from this? That is with the rows written out in full.

Comment: Just add `.reset_index(name='ID_2')` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `apply()` it might be quicker using a vectorised approach:

```py
import numpy as np

df['count'] = df['ID_0']  # copy column for counting

df = df.groupby(['ID_0', 'ID_1']).agg({
    'ID_2' : np.sum,
    'count': np.size
}).reset_index()

df['ID_2'] /= df['count']
df = df.drop(['count'], axis=1)
```